# Creating rasters with exactly 1km x 1km resolution in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I am using QGIS 2.18.11. I want to create grids with cell size that is exactly 1km by 1km using Raster>Conversion>Rasterize(Vector to Raster) and Raster>Grid(Interpolation). My area of interest is southern Pennsylvania. I need the cell size to be exact because my variables are measured per-square-km, and I need to be able to sum over grid cells.

I have tried all sorts of different combinations of CRS for the project and for the vector shapefiles I am converting, and set the cell size at 1000 pixels by 1000 pixels, but I cant get it to give me a raster with exactly 1km by 1km resolution. When I measure the cell size for the raster that is created, it comes out at around 1.3 km, with the vertical dimension shorter than the horizontal dimension.

Curiously, I can create a vector grid that is exactly 1km by 1km, but I dont see how that helps me.

What combination of project CRS and shapefile CRS can I use?

Comment: Originally, which CRS did you used?

Comment: I think I have found a workaround. I set the project CRS to NAD83 / Pennsylvania South and saved all vector shapefiles in that CRS. That CRS displays with meters as the X and Y coordinate measure.  I then used Raster>Conversion>Rasterize, setting Raster size in pixels = 400. I then edited the text in the box by adding "-te xmin ymin xmax ymax" where xmax- xmin and ymax-xmax were exactly 400,000. This gave me a 400 by 400 cell raster with each cell exactly 1km by 1km.

Comment: TheVector to Raster tool in QGIS 3 has an option for setting the cell size in georefererenced units. The grid tools do not seem to have that setting in UI but I guess that it is possible to set the GDAL option -tr (target resolution) by hand. Could you have a try with QGIS 3?